# Iterating over group and counting the matches between data frame

Tags: r

Apologize if the title of the question is not so clear.

I have two `data frame` as below:

```
df1
NAME   FOLLOWS
san    big supa
san    EAU
san    simulate
san    spang
glyn   guido
glyn   claire
glyn   vincent
glyn   dan
glyn   peter
glyn   EAU


df2
FOLLOWS
guido
vincent
EAU
EUSC
brian
simulate
peter
```

I would like to `count` matches between`df1$FOLLOWS` and `df2$FOLLOWS` for each `NAME` in `df1` and also the length of `df1$FOLLOWS` for each `NAME` in `df1`. For these data frame, I am expecting output like this:

```
df3
NAME LENGTH_FOLLOWS COUNT_Match
san        4            2
glyn       6            4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge df1 with df2 first which will keep only values present in df1. then you can simply count the instance.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select NAME, count(NAME) as LENGTH_FOLLOWS , count(Actual_F) as COUNT_Match from (select t1.*, t2.FOLLOWS as Actual_F from df1 t1 left join df2 t2 on t1.FOLLOWS=t2.FOLLOWS) group by NAME')
```

Or using base R

```
df1$index=match(df1$FOLLOWS, df2$FOLLOWS)
aggregate(cbind(df1$FOLLOWS,df1$index), by = list(df1$NAME) , FUN = function(x) length(x[!is.na(x)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the first data.frame to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`) and join `on` with the 'df2' to create an index column ('ind').  Then, grouped by 'NAME', we get the number of rows (`.N`) and the `sum` of logical vector of non-NA elements in 'ind'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, ind := 1, on = .(FOLLOWS)]
df1[, .(LENGTH_FOLLOWS = .N, COUNT_MATCH = sum(!is.na(ind))), NAME]
#   NAME LENGTH_FOLLOWS COUNT_MATCH
#1:  san              4           2
#2: glyn              6           4
```